# How to get id of a Sibling by using Class in JQuery

Tags: html, jquery, class

I am a little bit confused to access the sibling of an element by its class using jQuery.

It returns:

> Branch Name:undefined
>
> Branch City: [object Object]

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".ifsc_code").on("keyup", function() {
    console.log("Branch Name:" + $(this).parent().parent().parent().find("input.branch_name").attr('id'));
    console.log("Branch City:" + $(this).siblings(".branch_city"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="form-group form-float">
    <label class="form-label">IFSC Code*</label>
    <div class="form-line">
      <input id="ifsc_code" type="text" name="ifsc_code" minlength="11" maxlength="11" class="form-control ifsc_code" required>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="form-group form-float">
    <label class="form-label">Branch Name*</label>
    <div class="form-line">
      <input id="branch_name" type="text" name="branch_name" class="form-control branch_name" readonly>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I Have three times of the same code used as dynamic code with same classes so that I only want to perform this by using class.

Thanks

Comment: You select `.form-group` using `$(this).parent().parent().parent()` that hasn't `.branch_name`

Comment: Why do you need the triple `.parent()`?  Is there a reason why you cannot just do `$("input.branch_name")` instead?

Comment: Your DOM traversal is incorrect, and there is no `.branch_city` element. You don't need the DOM traversal anyway, as the element has an `id` on it, which must be unique, so just select by that. The error itself is because you're logging a jQuery object, not a value you want to retrieve from it.

Answer (score 1):

You were missing a `parent()` in the chain.
I would recommend using `closest(".col-sm-4")` or give that `div` some meaningful class and use it instead.
Also, `branch-city` is nowhere to be found on your HTML how do you suppose to find it?
I've commented it since I can't guess where it should be or what it is.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".ifsc_code").on("keyup", function() {
    console.log("Branch Name:" + $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find("input.branch_name").attr('id'));
    // There is no element with class 'branch_city'
    // console.log("Branch City:" + $(this).siblings(".branch_city"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="form-group form-float">
    <label class="form-label">IFSC Code*</label>
    <div class="form-line">
      <input id="ifsc_code" type="text" name="ifsc_code" minlength="11" maxlength="11" class="form-control ifsc_code" required>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="form-group form-float">
    <label class="form-label">Branch Name*</label>
    <div class="form-line">
      <input id="branch_name" type="text" name="branch_name" class="form-control branch_name" readonly>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Actually, if you want the elments to interact via hierarchy relations (and not searching the whole DOM) I would wrap both `div` in a container `div` with some class, let's say `container`, and then I would do:

```
console.log("Branch Name:" + $(this).closest(".container").find("input.branch_name").attr('id'));
```

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just dump code on them.

Comment: Also, you've just commented out the part about `branch_city`...?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I published a working script in my opinion then edited it with an explanation. You were simply quicker then me :)

Answer (score 0):

You trying to select `.form-group` using `$(this).parent().parent().parent()` that hasn't `.branch_name` child. Use this instead

```
$(this).closest(".col-sm-4").next().find("input.branch_name")
```

```js
$(".ifsc_code").on("keyup", function(){
    console.log("Branch Name:"+$(this).closest(".col-sm-4").next().find("input.branch_name").attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="form-group form-float">
  <label class="form-label">IFSC Code*</label>
    <div class="form-line">
      <input id="ifsc_code" type="text" name="ifsc_code"  minlength="11" maxlength="11" class="form-control ifsc_code" required>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="form-group form-float">
  <label class="form-label">Branch Name*</label>
    <div class="form-line">
     <input id="branch_name" type="text" name="branch_name" class="form-control branch_name" readonly>
    </div>
  </div>
```